# Assigning simple variable values, testing them later- best way to prevent repetitive code?

Tags: php, refactoring

How would I improve this code so that I am not repeating the same function over and over? I am struggling with creating a function for this, as the variable names need to be set specifically for use later in the code.

Code here...

```
if (in_array("knownValue", $array)) {
    $variableA = true;
} else {
    $variableA = false;
}
if (in_array("knownValue", $array)) {
    $variableB = true;
} else {
    $variableB = false;
}
if (in_array("knownValue", $array)) {
    $variableC = true;
} else {
    $variableC = false;
}
if (in_array("knownValue", $array)) {
    $variableD = true;
} else {
    $variableD = false;
}
```

Used later in the code as...

```
if ($variableA) {
    //do stuff...
} else {
    //do other stuff...
}
if ($variableB) {
    //do stuff...
} else {
    //do other stuff...
}
etc...
```

Edit-

Thanks, I thnk I just needed to sleep on it! Managed to condense the code to

```
<select class='selectpicker width100 updateAbilities' name='staffAbliities[]' multiple>";
    function renderOption($ability, $title, $array) {
            if (in_array($ability, $array)) {
                echo "
        <option data-content='<img src='images/abilities/$ability.png'> $title' value='$ability' selected>
            $title
        </option>";
    } else {
        echo "
            <option data-content='<img src='images/abilities/$ability.png'> $title' value='$ability'>
                $title
            </option>";
        }
    }
    renderOption("ops", "Operations Manager", $abilities);
    renderOption("guide_manager", "Guide Manager", $abilities);
    renderOption("senior_guide", "Senior Guide", $abilities);
    renderOption("guide", "Guide", $abilities);
    renderOption("trainee_guide", "Trainee Guide", $abilities);
    renderOption("big_bus", "Full PCV License", $abilities);
    renderOption("small_bus", "Small PCV License", $abilities);
    renderOption("wfr", "Wilderness First Responder", $abilities);
    renderOption("ice_climber", "Ice Climber", $abilities);
    echo "
</select>
```

Comment: Did "knownValue" is different every time ?Or this is exact string you look into array on every check?

Comment: It's different each time.

Comment: You can try with short if syntax to save some code; $variableA = (in_array("knownValue", $array))? true : false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first check with variables is unnecessary.
Your code will work fine without first part. You can try this this

```
$yourKeyForCheck = 'knownValue'

 if (array_value($yourKeyForCheck, $array)) {
   //do stuff 
 } else {
   //do other stuff...
 }
```

EDIT:
 I think this is more elegant decision

```
$aOptions = [
    [   'name'          =>  'ops',
        'title'         =>  'Operations Manager',
        'abilities'     =>  $abilities,
    ],
    [   'name'          =>  'guide_manager',
        'title'         =>  'Guide Manager',
        'abilities'     =>  $abilities,
    ],
    [   'name'          =>  'senior_guide',
        'title'         =>  'Senior Guide',
        'abilities'     =>  $abilities,
    ],
    [   'name'          =>  'guide',
        'title'         =>  'Guider',
        'abilities'     =>  $abilities,
    ],
    [   'name'          =>  'ops',
        'title'         =>  'Operations Manager',
        'abilities'     =>  $abilities,
    ],
];

<select class='selectpicker width100 updateAbilities' name='staffAbliities[]' multiple>";
<?php forech($aOptions as $aOption) { ?>
    <option 
        data-content='<img src='images/abilities/$ability.png'>
        <?php echo $aOption['title']?>';
        value='<?php echo $aOption['abilities']; ?>'
        <?php echo in_array($ability, $array)? selected : '' ?>
        $title
    </option>";
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thnk I just needed to sleep on it! Managed to condense the code to